# Next.js placeholder blur on Image not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a dynamic route called /titles/[slug].js . When I get there for the first time everything works fine the placeholder="blur" on every image is working, and I have also some animation based on if it's in the viewport with npm react-intersection-observer. But when go from for example from '/titles/pac-man/' to '/titles/walking-dead/' The placeholder blur. is not working anymore and the animations don't seem to work anymore.

Could it be if you go from /titles/[slug].js to /titles/[slug].js, the useStates/useEffects stays the same and doesn't update to original state when the component loads?

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
    if (inView) {
      setShow(true);
    }
  }, [inView]);
```

Or is it something else?

Comment: Did you console log the inView value to see if it changed? otherwise add more dependency to useEffect such as the "slug"?

Answer (score 1):

You could use local storage:

```
// useLocalStorage.js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

/*
first param is just a key in local storage
*/
export default function useLocalStorage(
    key
    initialValue
) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
        if (typeof localStorage !== "undefined") {
            const jsonValue = localStorage.getItem(key)
            if (jsonValue != null) return JSON.parse(jsonValue)
        }

        if (typeof initialValue === "function") {
            return initialValue()
        } else {
            return initialValue
        }
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value))
    }, [key, value])

    return [value, setValue]
}
```

And then replace useState with useLocalStorage like this:

```
const [show, setShow] = useLocalStorage("show", false);
```